# Reusable event listener callback within class

Tags: javascript

I write code in pure JS and I need to have reusable callback for my event listener within the class. It is required to meet following:

- reusable by another functions
- event listener needs to be revocable by another functions
- I need to pass argument (event)
- I need to be possible to call another function from the callback (this.doSomething())

I tried define callback as method and also as function expression but every time I solve one issue another occurred. I have walked through many questions here too but still can not make my code to work.

```
class Foo {

    constructor() {
        functionA()

        this.howAndWhereToDefineThisCallback = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }



    functionA() {
        let el = document.getElementById('element1');

        el.addEventListener( 'click', howAndWhereDefineThisCallback );

        this.functionB();
    }



    functionB() {
        let el = document.getElementById('element1');

        el.removeEventListener( 'click', howAndWhereToDefineThisCallback );
    }



    doSomething() {
        // something meaningful
    }
}
```

How can I modify my code to use it the way I just described?

Comment: I don't understand very well what's the problem. If you want to reuse that callback, simply define it outside the class where you will use it and pass it to the constructor. Because of the semantics of the `this` keyword it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an implementation:

```js
// Callback defined outside the class.
function callback(event) {
  this.doSomething();
}

class Foo {

    constructor(cb) {
        // Important: You have to bind it.
        this.cb = cb.bind(this);
        this.functionA();
    }

    functionA() {
        let el = document.getElementById('element1');
        el.addEventListener('click', this.cb);
    }

    functionB() {
        let el = document.getElementById('element1');
        el.removeEventListener('click', this.cb);
    }
  
    doSomething() {
        console.log('doing something...');
    }
}

const foo = new Foo(callback);
// foo.functionB();
```

```html
<button id="element1">
  Click here
</button>
```

Comment: I think I finally got it. The right implementation of function bind() was my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: one more question... What if I want to pass another parameter. Not just an 'event' but also 'el'

Comment: @TomášVavřinka [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exxXdR) you have a rough idea of how to do it. It can require a little refactoring of `functionB()`, but that's up to you.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your callback function, simply put it outside of your class scope. In order to call another function from your callback, just put that function as a argument of your callback, for example:

```
var howAndWhereToDefineThisCallback = function(event, anotherCallback) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (anotherCallback) anotherCallback();
}
```

To use the callback in your class method:

```
el.removeEventListener( 'click', function(event) {
   howAndWhereToDefineThisCallback(event, this.doSomething);
});
```